# R - Spatial Join Between SpatialPoints (GPS coordinates) and SpatialLinesDataFrame

Tags: r, join, spatial, lines, points

I am working on a university project which combines data science and GIS. We need to find an open-source solution capable of obtaining additional information from a massive GPS coordinates dataset. Clearly, I cannot use any API with daily request limit.

#### THE DATA

Here you can find a sample of the dataset the Professor provided us:

```
longitude <- c(10.86361, 10.96062, 10.93032, 10.93103, 10.93212)        
latitude <- c(44.53355, 44.63234, 44.63470, 44.63634, 44.64559)
longlat <- data.frame(longitude, latitude)
ID <- seq.int(1, 10)
```

#### FIRST TASK: Already Accomplished!

The first step was joining my `SpatialPoints` with a `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` using `over()` of `rgeos`. The `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` was obtained through `getData('GADM', country='ITA', level=3)` of `rgeos`.
For this first accomplished task, the objective was to associate to each GPS coordinates the information about `City` and `Region` which they belong to.
An example of the result I was able to obtain is:

```
require(sp)
require(rgeos)
my_spdf <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords = longlat, data = ID, proj4string = CRS(" +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 "))
italy_administrative_boundaries_level3 <- getData('GADM', country='ITA', level=3)
result <- over(my_spdf, italy_administrative_boundaries_level3)[, c("NAME_0", "NAME_1", "NAME_2", "NAME_3")]
result$ID <- ID
print(result)
```

#### SECOND TASK: MY QUESTION

Now the stuff become tricky because I need to associate additional and deeper information like `road_name` and `road_type`.
This information are contained in the shapefiles created on OpenStreetMap and available at: **download.geofabrik.de/europe/italy.html**.
I loaded the shapefile in R obtaining a `SpatialLinesDataFrame`:

```
require(rgdal)
shapefile_roads <- readOGR(dsn = "./road", layer = "roads")
```

Then, I naively tried to apply the same technique as for joining `SpatialPoints` and `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame`:

```
result <- over(my_spdf, shapefile_roads)
```

Clearly, the result is just `NA`. One possible reason that came into my mind was that the coordinates of `my_df` are not in the exact position of the `Lines` in `shapefile_roads`, therefore, I should need some kind of radius parameter. However, I am not really sure.

Can you suggest me the correct approach to perform this spatial join between my `SpatialPoints` and the attributes of the `SpatialLinesDataFrame` obtained from the `road_shapefile` of OpenStreetMap?

Please if something is not very clear do not hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your example data

```
library(raster)
longitude <- c(10.86361, 10.96062, 10.93032, 10.93103, 10.93212)        
latitude <- c(44.53355, 44.63234, 44.63470, 44.63634, 44.64559)
longlat <- data.frame(longitude, latitude)
ID <- data.frame(ID=1:5)
ita_gadm3 <- getData('GADM', country='ITA', level=3)[, c("NAME_0", "NAME_1", "NAME_2", "NAME_3")]
 #use `sp::over` or `raster::extract`
 result <- extract(ita_gadm3, longlat)
```

Some roads:

```
road <- spLines(cbind(longitude+.1, latitude), cbind(longitude-.1, rev(latitude)), cbind(longitude-.1, latitude+1), crs=crs(ita_gadm3))
```

Now find the nearest road segment. You can use `geosphere::dist2Line` because you are using angular (lon/lat) coordinates.

```
library(geosphere)
geosphere::dist2Line(longlat, road)
#     distance      lon      lat ID
#[1,] 2498.825 10.83212 44.53355  2
#[2,] 5527.646 11.03032 44.63470  1
#[3,] 5524.227 10.86062 44.63634  2
#[4,] 5577.372 10.86062 44.63634  2
#[5,] 5756.113 10.86062 44.63634  2
```

Note the variable `ID` which refers back to the roads. The problem is that dist2line is currently slow and you have a large data set.

The alternative is to transform your spatial data to a planar coordinate system appropriate for Italy and use gDistance.

```
library(rgeos)
library(rgeos)
sp <- SpatialPoints(longlat, proj4string=crs(ita_gadm3))
spita <- spTransform(sp, "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=15 +k=0.9996 +x_0=2520000 +y_0=0 +ellps=intl +units=m")
rdita <- spTransform(road, "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=15 +k=0.9996 +x_0=2520000 +y_0=0 +ellps=intl +units=m")

gd <- gDistance(rdita, spita, byid=TRUE)
a <- apply(gd, 1, which.min)
a
#1 2 3 4 5 
#2 1 2 2 2
```

That is, point 2 is closest to road 1. The other points are closest to road 2.
You probably need to do that in batches of points or tiles to avoid getting a distance matrix that is too large.

The buffer solution suggested by Sébastien could work in principle, but gets really complicated as there is no good buffer size. At the one hand, points may be outside any buffer and, at the other hand, they may overlap with several buffers. If you use buffers, `sp::over` returns an arbitrary match if there are multiple matches, whereas `raster::extract` will return them all. Neither is pretty, and I would avoid this approach. Illustrated here:

```
b <- buffer(road, width=.15, dissolve=F)
plot(b)
lines(road, col='red', lwd=2)
points(longlat, pch=20, col='blue')

extract(b, longlat)
#   point.ID poly.ID
#1         1       1
#2         1       2
#3         2       2
#4         2       1
#5         3       2
#6         3       1
#7         4       2
#8         4       1
#9         5       1
#10        5       2

over(sp, b)
#1 2 3 4 5 
#2 2 2 2 2
```

Comment: @RoberH thank you for your reply. However, I think my long post confused you because instead of using `shapefile_roads <- readOGR(dsn = "./road", layer = "roads")` where the road shapefile was obtained at download.geofabrik.de/europe/italy.html; you used `getData('GADM', country='ITA', level=3)` which is the `spatialpolygonsdataframe` I used to accomplish the first task.

Comment: I do not think so. I just did not want to download a file if there is no need for it, so I created some roads in code. The object is called "road" and they clearly are lines (SpatialLines}.

Comment: thank you. Therefore, your code should give me the Address associated to the GPS coordinates if they fell inside the buffer of that line, correct?
Furthermore, I guess that to make the process less ambiguous I should try to clean the road shapefile as much as possible?

Comment: It associates a point with the nearest road. I shows how to *not* use buffers, and I explain why not. Did you run the code and inspect it and the results?

Comment: I cannot run the test tonight because I am on the tablet. Tomorrow I can use the computer of the university and I will update you about the results. Thank you very much.

Comment: I associated `CRS(" +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 "))` to both `sp` and `roads`. When I run `gd <- gDistance(road, sp, byid=TRUE)` I obtain: `Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘is.projected’ for signature ‘"data.frame"’
In addition: Warning message:
In RGEOSDistanceFunc(spgeom1, spgeom2, byid, "rgeos_distance") :
  Spatial object 1 is not projected; GEOS expects planar coordinates`. The `Spatial object` one is `roads` and both are `spatial` objects. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That is the same as `crs(ita_gadm3)` that I use. Apparently your sp has become a data.frame. But I cannot see your code, so I cannot help. Perhaps for another question. The warning is as expected (you need to project to a planar system first.

Comment: I just realized that it accept only SpatialPoints and not SpatialPointsDataFrame. How would you project this data to a planar system first?

Comment: I have added that to my answer

Comment: Great answer. It works. Now I just need to figure out how to make feasible the gDistance considering such a big shapefile.

Comment: have you got any idea about how to optimize this approach or whether there is any alternative (i.e. Python / QGis). Because I have 3,000,000 points to match to around 1,000,000 lines and it has a pace of 60,000 points matched every 14 hours.

Answer (score 1):

You need to join polygons with your points, not Lines. To do so, you can create a buffer area around your Lines using `rgeos::gBuffer()`. Be careful, because the buffer area will be in the coordinate system of your Lines. Probably degrees (wgs84) in your case (Verify it). Choose the correct distance (`width`) according to your case.

```
LinesBuffer <- rgeos::gBuffer(shapefile_roads, width = 0.01)
```

Then you will be able to join points with "LinesBuffer" using `over` (if they are in the same coordinates system).

```
result <- over(my_spdf, LinesBuffer)
```

Comment: Could you please extend a little bit maybe also by presenting the result of a practical example?  There is no need to use my specific data, you can get a random gps from a small city so you can easily download the shapefile of that specific city using its `bbox`. I would like to understand how to obtain the street address starting from a gps point and a `spatiallinesdataframe` from openstreetmap.

Comment: Seymour, *you* are supposed to provide example data (in code, not files) and Sébastin's suggestions *are* implemented in RobertH's answer.

Comment: I supplied you with sample data of course but I cannot supply you with a shapefile. That's why I shared with you the link about where to download them.

Comment: The point is that you do not need to supply a file, as you can create some example data with code